# ol li count in two column in chrome browser

Tags: html, css, html-lists

i am try to show ol li in two column in chrome browser. but get below mentioned result, look at picture pls.

my code:

```
 #answerlistli  {

        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -moz-column-gap: 20px;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
        column-count: 2;
        column-gap: 20px;

    }
```

```
       <ol  id="answerlistli" style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bolder;">

                    <li id="td1"></li>
                    <li id="td2"></li>
                    <li id="td3"></li>
                    <li id="td4"></li>
                    <li id="td5"></li>
                    <li id="td6"></li>
                    <li id="td7"></li>
                    <li id="td8"></li>
                    <li id="td9"></li>
                    <li id="td10"></li>
                    <li id="td11"></li>
                    <li id="td12"></li>
                    <li id="td13"></li>
                    <li id="td14"></li>
                    <li id="td15"></li>
                    <li id="td16"></li>
                    <li id="td17"></li>
                    <li id="td18"></li>
                    <li id="td19"></li>
                    <li id="td20"></li>
                    <li id="td21"></li>
                    <li id="td22"></li>
                    <li id="td23"></li>
                    <li id="td24"></li>
                    <li id="td25"></li>
                    <li id="td26"></li>
                    <li id="td27"></li>
                    <li id="td28"></li>
                    <li id="td29"></li>
                    <li id="td30"></li>
                    <li id="td31"></li>
                    <li id="td32"></li>
                    <li id="td33"></li>

                </ol>
```

but in second column numbers dont seems in chrome. but in mozilla it works.

picture in chrome :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "magic" is around `list-style-position`, it should be inside:

```css
#answerlistli  {
  list-style-position: inside;

  -moz-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-gap: 20px;
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
  column-count: 2;
  column-gap: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ol  id="answerlistli" style="font-size: 20px; font-weight: bolder;">
    <li id="td1"></li>
    <li id="td2"></li>
    <li id="td3"></li>
    <li id="td4"></li>
    <li id="td5"></li>
    <li id="td6"></li>
    <li id="td7"></li>
    <li id="td8"></li>
    <li id="td9"></li>
    <li id="td10"></li>
    <li id="td11"></li>
    <li id="td12"></li>
    <li id="td13"></li>
    <li id="td14"></li>
    <li id="td15"></li>
    <li id="td16"></li>
    <li id="td17"></li>
    <li id="td18"></li>
    <li id="td19"></li>
    <li id="td20"></li>
    <li id="td21"></li>
    <li id="td22"></li>
    <li id="td23"></li>
    <li id="td24"></li>
    <li id="td25"></li>
    <li id="td26"></li>
    <li id="td27"></li>
    <li id="td28"></li>
    <li id="td29"></li>
    <li id="td30"></li>
    <li id="td31"></li>
    <li id="td32"></li>
    <li id="td33"></li>
</ol>
```